# Is it possible for backtracking N-queens to produce O(n^2) time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, backtracking, n-queens, recursive-backtracking

The backtracking approach for n-queens is clearly O(n!). However I am looking at these links here:
https://algodaily.com/challenges/classical-n-queen-problem

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-queen-problem-backtracking-3/

They give O(n^2) time complexity. How is that the case? I read their code, and their solutions appear to be O(n!). For each row, try all columns. That's n*(n-1)*(n-2)... etc I have no idea how they're getting O(n^2).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059422

Comment: @hidefromkgb I saw that. Their n^2 approach listed is not backtracking, so those links I gave make no sense

Comment: Same with me. Chances are they just copied from the same source without verifying what it said?